# Link <a href="..."/> is not working in nopcommerce in submenu

Tags: c#, nopcommerce

I am new to NopCommerce and I want to add submenu in my store.

I have added my submenu, but when I click on it, the link which I have given in  is not working and it gives me an error.

My code is as below:

Menu View File

```
  <li id="DevelopmentItem">
      <a href="">Development</a> 
      <ul id="Developmentsubmenu" class="dropdown-ul">
          **<li><a href="~/Common/NpcDevelopment">NPC Development</a></li>
            <li><a href="~/Indies/NPCExtensions">NPC Extension Development</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">NPC Customize</a></li>**
        </ul>
  </li>

  <script type="text/javascript">
        $('#DevelopmentItem').live('mouseenter', function () {
            $('#Developmentsubmenu').addClass('active');
        });
        $('#DevelopmentItem').live('mouseleave', function () {
            $('#Developmentsubmenu').removeClass('active');
        });
  </script>
```

CommonController.cs file

```
 public ActionResult NpcDevelopment()
 {
     return View();
 }
```

NpcDevelopment View File

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "NpcDevelopment";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_ColumnsOne.cshtml";
}

<h2>NpcDevelopment</h2>
```

I can't find my fault. Can anyone help me?

Comment: What exactly is happening when it's "not working"? And what's the error it gives you?

Comment: it gives me an error like page not found.

Comment: have you tried to put "/Common/NpcDevelopment" instead of "~/Common/NpcDevelopment" ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using mvc3 to develop? If you are, replace 
    `<a href="~/Common/NpcDevelopment"> with this`
    `<a href="@Url.Action("{Action}", "{Controller}")">`for example:
`<a href="@Url.Action("NpcDevelopment", "Common")">`